# JSF greater than zero validator

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

How do you create a validator in JSF that validates the input text if it is greater than zero?

```
<h:inputText id="percentage" value="#{lab.percentage}">
    <f:validateDoubleRange minimum="0.000000001"/>
</h:inputText>
```

I have the code above but I am not sure if this is optimal.  Although it works but if another number lesser than this is needed then I need to change the jsf file again.
The use case is that anything that is greater than zero is okay but not negative number.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This may be of interest: http://www.kianworknotes.com/2013/06/jsf-number-validator-with-regular.html

Comment: Yes using validateDoubleRange with minimum = 0 would allow zero also which is what I dont like either...

Comment: Ok pls check my answer below and let me know (sorry couldn't test it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create a custom validator, i.e. a class implementing [`javax.faces.validator.Validator`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/validator/Validator.html), and annotate it with `@FacesValidator("positiveNumberValidator")`.

Implement the `validate()` method like this:

```
@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) throws ValidatorException {

    try {
        if (new BigDecimal(value.toString()).signum() < 1) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Validation failed.", 
                    "Number must be strictly positive");
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg); 
        } 
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Validation failed.", "Not a number");
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        throw new ValidatorException(msg); 
    }
}
```

And use it in the facelets page like this:

```
<h:inputText id="percentage" value="#{lab.percentage}">
    <f:validator validatorId="positiveNumberValidator" />
</h:inputText>
```

Useful link: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-validator-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: Thanks this has been my solution!