# Java Regex for positive numbers only excluding zero

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling with java regex.
I want to validate if a number is greater than zero and it should not be negative also

```
0.00011 - GOOD
1.222 - GOOD
0.000 - BAD
-1.1222 - BAD
```

So anything above zero is okay.
Is this possible in java regex?

Comment: Any reason for doing this with regex?

Comment: I doubt you are "struggling" with that. Can you show what you already have?

Comment: @Kobi My question is related to my other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18071219/jsf-greater-than-zero-validator As nobody is answering so I thought regex would help me.  But based on the answers below, I think I am left with using custom validators.  Thanks again for your time though

Comment: I appreciate the answers and I got cleared on some concepts on my other threads.  Moderator can closed this if they want

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this with regexes. Do this with `BigDecimal`:

```
// True if and only if number is strictly positive
new BigDecimal(inputString).signum() == 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Why regex?

You can simply do something like following

```
 double num=0.00011;
    if(num>0){
        System.out.println("GOOD");
    }else{
        System.out.println("BAD");
    }
```

Or if you rally want to do this in hard way you can try some thing as follows too

```
 String num="-0.0001";
   char sign=num.split("\\.")[0].charAt(0);
   if(sign=='-' || Double.parseDouble(num)==0.0){
       System.out.println("BAD");
   }else {
       System.out.println("GOOD");
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^(0\\.\\d*[1-9]\\d*)|([1-9]\\d*(\\.\\d+)?)$
```

Which will match

```
0.1
0.01
0.010
0.10
1.0
1.1
1.01
1.010
3
```

but not

```
0
0.0
-0.0
-1
-0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better not to solve it using regex, still here is one of the solution how to solve it using regex:

```
 public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    String str = "0.0000";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^-[0-9]+.+[0-9]*)|(^[0]+.+[0]+$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    if (m.find()) {
      System.out.println("False");
    }else{
      System.out.println("True");
    }
  }
```

Here is the [demo](http://ideone.com/LUcj9l)